# problem with 1m interval in get_data_yahoo(pandas_datareader)

Tags: python, yahoo-api, pandas-datareader

I wrote

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AAPL", start='2020-04-12', end='2020-04-13', interval="m")
```

And I got a error

```
KeyError 'Date'
```

I heard people saying Yahoo finance API is down but I still can get the following code working correctly

```
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AAPL", start='2020-04-12', end='2020-04-13')
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to get 1 minute interval historical data, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas_datareader interval="m"` means 1 month you need yfinance.

> 1. `pip download yfinance`
> 2. `import yfinance`
> 3. `a = yfinance.download(ticker="your symbol",period="5d",interval="1m")`

Comment: If you have a start date (2007-4-1) and an end date (2014-2-1) for example, and you want to get a 1 minute historical data to "AAPL" for example. How do you write that!?