# How to collect data in range from Yahoo Finance?

Tags: python, python-requests, yahoo-finance

I am using a script which uses this line:

```
    res = requests.get('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{symbol}?range={data_range}&interval={data_interval}'.format(**locals()))
```

to collect stock data from Yahoo Finance. Currently, I am inputting values such as **'1d'** for **data_range** which gives me the data from the past day. However, what do I enter if I want to collect data say from 2020-11-24 to 2020-11-25 (instead of from past x days)?

Comment: You can use period1 and period2 as query parameters instead of using range. They have to be in a time stamp format (i.e. period1=1606490125&period2=1606490239

Comment: Yeah, ok thanks. And those numbers are the number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970 if I haven't messed up the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the Selenium library.Because you need to handle click event and for the page to relode to get the new updated stock data check bellow

http://lmari.hatenablog.com/entry/selenium-fin

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

```
#!pip install pandas-datareader

import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data

stock = 'RENT3.SA'
source = 'yahoo'

# Set date range
start = datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 19)
end = datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27)

# Collect stock data
dataset = data.DataReader(stock, source, start, end)

goog_df['Adj Close'].plot(kind='line', grid=True, title='RENT3 Adjusted Closes')
```

Comment: would this be able to collect intraday data (for eg data for every minute of the day)?

Comment: @Ken check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61810596/problem-with-1m-interval-in-get-data-yahoopandas-datareader

Comment: so I guess I would need yfinance?